Sumsets with the factorials

Question. Let $n\ge 3$ be an integer and consider the Abelian group $X:=\mathbb{Z}/n!\mathbb{Z}$. Let $A$ be the set of factorials in $X$, that is,
$$
A:=\{1!,2!,\ldots,n!\}+n!\mathbb{Z}. 
$$
Is it true that if $B\subseteq X$ satisfies
$$
A+B=X
$$
then $|B|\ge n!/100$?

Ps. Here $A+B:=\{x+y: x\in A, y \in B\}$. An example of such set $B$ is
$$
B_0=\{3,6,9,\ldots,n!\}+n!\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Indeed, since $A$ contains all the remainder modulo $3$, then $A+B_0=X$. In this example, $|B_0|=n!/3$.
On the other hand, since $|A+B|\le |A|\cdot |B|$, then every $B$ has to satisfy $n! \le n\cdot |B|$, hence $|B|\ge n!/n$. Is $B_0$ a "nearly optimal" example or $B$ can be much smaller?

I think your conjecture is false. I used your own idea and wrote some simple code, which allowed me to check that for $p = 991$ for instance, the number of residue classes mod $p$ reached by elements from the set $A$ is equal to $649$. With some more code, one can check that the maximum gap between two consecutive residue classes mod $p$ that come from $A$ is only of size $6$.
Now assume that $n \geq 991$. Then consider the set $B$ that contains all classes in $X$ that correspond to numbers $0, 1, \ldots, 5 \mod p$. I claim that $A + B = X$. Indeed, if $x \in X$, then consider the value $x \mod p$. By the above, there is an element $a \in A$ with $x - a \in \{ 0, \ldots, 5 \} \mod p$. Therefore $x - a \in B$ so we are done.
Finally, now $B$ is of size $6|X| / 991 < |X|/100$, answering your question negatively. In fact, using this method and choosing larger and larger primes, I expect one can create examples for which $B$ only represents an increasingly small fraction of $X$, but I would not be sure how to prove that at this time.
My SageMath (aka Python) code which I used to look for suitable primes in case you want to check:
for p in primes(1000):
    modlist = []
    for i in range(1,p):
        modthing = factorial(i) % p
        if not modthing in modlist:
            modlist.append(modthing)
    n = len(modlist)
    modlist = sorted(modlist)
    maxdiv = 0
    for j in range(n-1):
        div = modlist[j+1] - modlist[j]
        if div > maxdiv:
            maxdiv = div
    ratio = maxdiv / p
    print(p, n, maxdiv, ratio.numerical_approx(15))


This reminded me about the distribution of factorials modulo primes (see e.g. here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01198 ). It is conjectured that, as $n\to \infty$, $A$ covers $\approx (1-1/e)p$ remainders modulo a prime $p$. We do not know such remainders are "random" in such sense, but it is reasonable to expect that the largest gap is $o(n)$.

That explains why it seemed like for most primes $p$, the set $A$ would reach roughly around $60 %$ of the residue classes; an intriguing conjecture no doubt!
